# Sophomore + Junior + Senior

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

A class is attended by $n$ sophomores, $n$ juniors and $n$ seniors.  In how many ways can these students form $n$ groups of three people each if each group is to contain a sophomore, a junior, and a senior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, line up the sophmores in any way.  Next, line up the juniors across from the sophmores in any one of $n!$ ways.  After that, line up the seniors across from the juniors in any one of $n!$ ways.  The result is a total of $(n!)^2$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise from *A Walk Through Combinatorics: An Introduction to Enumeration and Graph Theory*.

Hint: Simplify the problem by taking away the seniors. Can you solve the problem now? What if you add the seniors back in?